# Swift: Reading plist - How to filter by key and read and append value only

Tags: ios, swift, plist

Swift 3

I'm trying to read a plist file to update my array for collection view.

My `menu.plist` has 6 items that I want to read and append to my array that uses `.count` to update the collection view.

Problem is I'm having trouble sorting the dictionary. I want to append the strings in value to my array but sort the transfer by the key which has the text "Item 0", "Item 1", etc. Because the array comes unorganized which makes it harder to use the switch statements on `didSelectItemAt`.

In the code I'm not using `key` only appending `value` to `mainGroup` array but its unorganized and I need to filter it by the plist `key`

Code in ViewDidLoad

```
var mainGroup = [String]()

var myDict: NSDictionary?
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "menu", ofType: "plist") {
    myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
}
if let dict = myDict {

    print(dict)

    for (_, value) in dict {

        mainGroup.append("\(value)")
    }

    print(mainGroup)
}
```

Plist

[image: pic 1]

Comment: Why is your plist a dictionary? It looks like it should be an array.

Comment: new to plist, what difference can it make? you can sort array

Comment: It really isn't a plist issue. You should use the proper data collection that best suits your needs. If you don't understand the difference between a dictionary and an array then I strongly suggest you read the overview in the documentation for the Dictionary and Array classes and/or review the [Collection Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID105) section in the Swift book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need sort your `dict.keys` array and the access to value by those sorted keys

**Full code**

```
var mainGroup = [String]()

    var myDict: [String:String]?
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "menu", ofType: "plist") {
        myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? [String:String]
    }
    if let dict = myDict {

        print(dict)

        for key in dict.keys.sorted() {

            mainGroup.append(dict[key]!)
        }



        print(mainGroup)
    }
```

## update

**Using array as @rmaddy says**

[image]

```
    var mainGroup = [String]()

    var myArray: [String]?
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "menu", ofType: "plist") {
        myArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) as? [String]
    }

    print(myArray)
```

Comment: In this case there doesn't appear to be any need to use a dictionary. The plist should just be an array of those values.

Comment: maybe you're right, but that is what OP needs, and is pretty trivial to do @rmaddy

Comment: @ReinierMelian it works perfect thank you, but should I convert the plist from Dictionary to Array?

Comment: I think if you don´t need to rapid access to any value using keys, you can use an array instead, as rmaddy says @BroSimple

Comment: @ReinierMelian how different would the code be? I tried NSArray instead of NSDictionary but a warning

Comment: thank you! just to learn, when switched to Array why don't you need key or value anymore it automatically gets value correctly?

Comment: because is an array, array is a collection of objects in this case objects defined in the plist as String, you need read the link provided by rmaddy in his comment to know more about collections, give it a try @BroSimple